# iLightbBox videos and iframes not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I purchased [iLightBox](http://ilightbox.net/) today but can't seem to get videos (youtube, hulu, vimeo, etc.) to open in the plugin's lightbox. Images are opening fine, just not videos or iframes.

I believe I have followed the [documentation](http://ilightbox.net/documentation.html) correctly.

Here is my html:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>iLightbox</title>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.requestAnimationFrame.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.mousewheel.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/ilightbox.packed.js"></script>

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/ilightbox.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/dark-skin/skin.css"/>
</head>

<body>
    <a href="http://www.oxleydogtrainingclub.org.au/bamboo%20dog.JPG" id="ilightbox" data-type="image">Image</a><br>

    <a href="http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gIp7vZuYzoA?autoplay=1&autohide=1&border=0&egm=0&showinfo=0'" id="ilightbox">Youtube</a><br>

    <a href='http://www.hulu.com/watch/424558'
   id="ilightbox"
   data-options="smartRecognition: true">Hulu</a><br>

    <a href='http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gIp7vZuYzoA?autoplay=1&autohide=1&border=0&egm=0&showinfo=0'
    id="ilightbox"
    data-type="iframe"
    data-options="width: 638, height: 360">Youtube (HTML5)</a>
    <script>
      $('#ilightbox').iLightBox();
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Can anyone tell me what I'am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found my problem.

Turns out you have to call the `iLightBox()` function for each item. For example:

```
$('#myImage1').iLightBox();
$('#myImage2').iLightBox();
$('#myVideo1').iLightBox();
$('#myVideo2').iLightBox();
```

Answer (score 1):

try using colorbox, it's free and easy to install and works for many platform (youtube, viemo, iframe, inline, ajax etc.[colorbox](http://www.jacklmoore.com/colorbox/example1/)

Comment: Thanks, but I found my problem. I didn't realise you have to call the jquery function (...$('#myVideo').iLightBox()...) for each iLightBox item.

Comment: i already purchased iLightBox, but i used and loved colorbox, is a professional free plugin (( i currently donated to it via paypal ))

Answer (score 0):

A little late to the game here, but you're using an ID instead of a class... it's only grabbing the first one because you're only supposed to have one element per ID.

Try changing it to `class="myVideo"` and calling `$(".myVideo").iLightBox();`